# Can I install provisioning profile, p12 and cert without using a github repository or S3 using fastlane match?

Tags: ios, react-native, github-actions, fastlane, fastlane-match

I am building out a CI/CD pipeline for iOS deployment and would like to generate builds all through command line prompts and this requires me to install provisioning profiles on the mac. I would like to use fastlane match but not store it in a github repository or s3 bucket but instead just have the certificates be in the same repository as the codebase. Does anyone know if fastlane match supports the import and installation of certs without creating a separate repo or s3 bucket etc?